# Linear mixed-effects regression on longitudinal data: Multicollinearity

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, panel-data, multicollinearity

Panel data: subjects' `value` are repeatedly measured over `time` points. Suppose the first half was the pretest (`grp=0`) and the second half received the intervention (`grp=1`).

Take [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/236443/306993) as an example:

```
  ID | time | grp | value |
  s_1| 1    |  0  | Q_11  |
  s_1| 2    |  0  | Q_12  |
  s_1| 3    |  0  | Q_13  |
  s_1| 4    |  1  | Q_14  |
  s_1| 5    |  1  | Q_15  |
  s_1| 6    |  1  | Q_16  |
```

Now, run a linear mixed-effecs regression `value ~ time * factor(grp) + (time | ID)`. Each subject `ID` will have its own intercept and slope over time.

However, my concern is that `grp` can be derived from `time`, i.e., `grp = ifelse(time <=3, 0, 1)`. This may be **collinearity** (I wonder if that's the exact word to use because one variable is categorical).

How do I fix the issue or even conduct another model? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to be concerned. Multicolinearity occurs when one column of the design matrix (the matrix of values of predictor variables) can be derived as a *linear combination* of the other columns. Your variable `grp` does not fall into that category.

As another example, consider the case of a polynomial regression model with the continuous predictors $x$ and $x^2$. The latter can be derived from the former -- and the two are correlated -- but multicolinearity isn't usually a problem (e.g., parameter estimates and their SEs are usually stable).